# Prove that $(1+x)^k/k + (1-x)^m/m\geq 1/k +1/m$ without calculus

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality, young-inequality

Note: this has been edited to make the question more general.

I want to show that $(1+x)^k/k + (1-x)^m/m$ is minimized at $x=0$ when $k,m\geq 1$ and $-1\leq x \leq1$.

Of course, I could take the first two derivatives, etc. However, the *real* statement that I need to prove is a more general multivariate version of this, and it is very ugly to take the gradient and Hessian of it in full generality.

What I'm really hoping is that there's some simple trick using Hölder's Inequality, or something related to it.

Comment: You should post that "*real* statement". This one can be written as $\,(y + x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x)^2 + 12 x^2 + 3 \ge 3\,$ which of course proves it, but wouldn't necessarily work for your other, untold question.

Comment: I have made it somewhat more general now (although, I also changed it to a single variable statement). For now, I want to avoid writing the full statement because it has a lot of parameters which obfuscate what's going on. However, if this statement is still too simple, I will add more to it!

Comment: If $k=1$ and $m=3$, it tends to $-\infty$ when $x\to + \infty$.

Comment: Sorry. Should have had constraints on x. Added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: Ahhhh... that's it! Thanks!